# how to include javascript error message when user input is invalid

Tags: javascript

When I input the values I am successfully able to give an output for the age, however I need a validation of the inputs that signals an error and pastes to the browser the warning message. I am using the if statement for this but it does not work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <form>
                Birth Year:
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="birthYear">
                <br>
                Current Year:
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="currentYear">
            </form>
            <button onclick="calculateAge()">Calculate Age</button>
            <div id="output"></div>



<script>
    function calculateAge() {
    var ghF = document.querySelector('[name="birthYear"]').value;
    var xhF = document.querySelector('[name="currentYear"]').value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You are either "+(xhF - ghF)+" or "+(xhF - ghF + 1)

    if (ghF) || (xhF) !== "number" {
        confirm("Invalid, please try again")
    }
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: View your syntax errors in the console. The condition following an `if` must be parenthesized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) method to parse the user input to a number:

```
var ghF = parseInt(document.querySelector('[name="birthYear"]').value, 10);
var xhF = parseInt(document.querySelector('[name="currentYear"]').value, 10);
```

and then check for NaN:

```
if (isNaN(ghF) || isNaN(xhF)) {
    // One of the two user inputs couldn't be parsed to a number
    alert('Invalid, please try again');
}
```

and do this check before actually using the values, for example put this in the `else` part of your condition:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You are either " + (xhF - ghF) + " or " + (xhF - ghF + 1);
```